# Clickable div tag using not() any div tags inside that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

A pretty unattractive title, but I'm not sure how other to explain it.

I have the following code which is my navigation bar. Each 'group' is an option with essentially a drop down. If you would like to view this visually, you can view it at www.titaniumwebdesigns.com

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <div id="line"><img src="/images/nav/line.png" alt="" /></div>
    <li>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="outside"><div class="sub a media"></div></div>
        <div class="inside"><div class="sub b gallery"></div></div>
        <div class="circle selected"><div class="sub c showcase"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text portfolio"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="outside"><div class="sub a everything-else"></div></div>
        <div class="inside"><div class="sub b development"></div></div>
        <div class="circle"><div class="sub c design"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text services"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="outside"><div class="sub a the-company"></div></div>
        <div class="inside"><div class="sub b the-director"></div></div>
        <div class="circle"><div class="sub c employees"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text about"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="outside"><div class="sub a arrange-a-meeting"></div></div>
        <div class="inside"><div class="sub b get-in-touch"></div></div>
        <div class="circle"><div class="sub c support"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text contact"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="outside"><div class="sub a facebook"></div></div>
        <div class="inside"><div class="sub b twitter"></div></div>
        <div class="circle"><div class="sub c blog"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text social"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</nav>
```

I would like the user to click on either .outside, .inside or .circle and for it to find out which index() it has to then find its link, which is will then either redirect or slide in using some nice jQuery effects. Here's an example:

```
var _0 = "portfolio.php";
var _1 = "showcase.php"; //etc...

//below within $(document).ready() {
$(".group div").not(".sub").click(function() {
  alert($(this).index()); //or find the appropriate page using the variables above
});
```

However it's just not working in the way it is intended. I understand that the .sub is within the selected divs but is there a way to ignore these even though they are within that div tag?  I want to click on .outside, .inside, .circle and something happens but at the same time, I want to click on .sub and for nothing to happen, even though they are inside the other divs.  The CSS requires them to be within those div tags but visually, they are removed from the div tag using CSS, so you're not clicking in the same place.

Comment: You do realize that this is completely inaccessible to users who navigate via keyboard. If you're going to use `div` rather than `a` at least add `tabindex=0` so the divs are focusable via keyboard and add some visually hidden text so they know what they are activating.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I understand that this isn't very keyboard friendly at the moment however I will ensure all accessibility options will be added once the main options are working correctly. I shall bear the tab index thing in mind when I get round to doing that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't do anything for the ones with class sub.  Like this:

```
//below within $(document).ready() {
$(".group div:odd").click(function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass("sub"))
  {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return;
  }
  alert($(this).index()); //or find the appropriate page using the variables above
});
```

Comment: This code looks great however the alert() does not pop up at all.  An alert within the if statement works great but anything after that does't seem to work at all, maybe because it's still detecting the .sub within the other div tags.

Comment: I'm not sure, I was not able to get your code to work on jsFiddle to test.

Comment: Would you like me to make a jsFiddle link with the complete code on? The website this is on at the moment is titaniumwebdesigns.com

Comment: I bet if you did you would be an answer quickly from me or someone else.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a more specific selector:

```
$(".group").children('div').click(...)
```

or

```
$(".group > div").click(...)
```

This will make only .inner, .outer, and .circle clickable.

Comment: Although this looks like the best solution, I have tried both of these in the very beginning and neither works correctly.